# How to run an existing stopped container and get inside the bash?

Tags: docker, containers

I am a newbie to Docker, and I know that in order to run a container I can use the following command:

```
docker run -it --name custom-container-name --hostname custom-hostname image-name bash
```

The previous command creates a container named `custom-container-name` which hostname is `custom-hostname`, and it uses the image `image-name`. I know that the `-it` flag gives me access to the `bash`. (please correct me if I am wrong)

Now, I have stopped this container, but I want use it again, so **what is the command I should use to open this container again with its bash**, as when I run the `docker run ...` command the first time it was created.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem I think you're running into is that the command you provide is exiting immediately and for the container to keep running it needs a command that will not exit. One way I've found to keep containers running is to use the -d option like so:

```
docker run -dt --name custom-container-name --hostname custom-hostname image-name
```

That should start it running as a daemon in the background. Then you can open a shell in the container with:

```
docker exec -it custom-container-name /bin/bash
```

If the default user for the image is root (or unset) this should provide you a root shell within the container.

You can use docker inspect to see the details of the image to see what the default command and user are:

```
docker inspect image-name | less
```

Also, if your container exists, and its status is "Exited", you can start that container, and then use `docker exec` as follows:

```
docker start custom-container-name
docker exec -it custom-container-name /bin/bash
```

Comment: your answer is good, I think you could add that using `docker start custom-container-name` and then `docker exec -it custom-container-name bash` solves this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to inspect a stopped container which works in every case and doesn't assume anything about the container is to turn the container into an image using `docker commit <CONTAINER_ID|CONTAINER_NAME>`. You can then run any command you like on it, including `bash`.

A more general answer as the accepted one didn't help me. In my case I have a container which builds something that runs for a very long time and is now stopped. I can't `docker start` it because it will exit immediately since the build is already finished. I also don't want to run it again or modify it because the build takes >5 hours and is extremely flaky.